# How to count how many certain tags there are in a source code in vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, tags

I have a source code (http://finder.fi/Elektroniikkaa+ja+komponentteja/JOT+Automation+Headquarters+Oulu/OULU/taloustiedot/417315) from which I want to extract the elements that are defined by the "td" tag and are after the

```
<td><div class="desc">Yrityksen henkilöstömäärä</div></td>
```

Here's the part of the source code:

```
    <tr class="even">
<td><div class="desc">Yrityksen liikevaihto (1000 EUR)</div></td>

    <td>20639000</td>

    <td>17240000</td>

    <td>11727000</td>

    <td>11177000</td>

    <td>3141000</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="desc">Liikevaihdon muutos%</div></td>

    <td>2.30</td>

    <td>-16.50</td>

    <td>-32.00</td>

    <td>-4.70</td>

    <td>-71.90</td>

</tr>

<tr class="even">
<td><div class="desc">Tilikauden tulos (1000 EUR)</div></td>

    <td>540000</td>

    <td>1542000</td>

    <td>-154000</td>

    <td>-569000</td>

    <td>5383000</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="desc">Liikevoitto%</div></td>

    <td>3.20</td>

    <td>-3.60</td>

    <td>-8.00</td>

    <td>-8.40</td>

    <td>-14.40</td>

</tr>

<tr class="even">
<td><div class="desc">Yrityksen henkilöstömäärä</div></td>

    <td>13827</td>

    <td>11895</td>

    <td>8016</td>

    <td>4829</td>

    <td>1842</td>

    </tr>'
```

The elements I'm trying to pull are always the last ones. But as the amount of tags varies from search to search I want to find out how many "td" tags there are in the code and work back from there to pull the last elements.

Comment: where is the code you have tried to accomplish this? without showing your efforts the question will most likely be closed or downvoted. That said, a simple google search on looping through HTML tags in VBA will yield you some help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to pull the required content you need something like:

```
Sub GetLastTDContent()

    Dim strCode     As String
    Dim strTemp     As Variant

    strCode = "<td>13827</td> <td>11895</td><td> <div class='desc'>Yrityksen henkilöstömäärä</div></td> <td>8888</td> <td>9999</td> other unnecessary stuff"

    ' Filtering the second part
    strTemp = Split(strCode, "Yrityksen henkilöstömäärä</div></td>")
    strTemp = strTemp(UBound(strTemp))
    strTemp = Trim(strTemp)

    strCode = strTemp
    Do While InStr(strCode, "<td>") > 0         ' Pick each <td>
        strTemp = Split(strCode, "<td>")(1)
        strTemp = Split(strTemp, "</td>")(0)    ' Now extract the part preceeding </td>
        MsgBox strTemp
        strCode = Mid(strCode, InStr(strCode, "</td>") + Len("</td>"))  ' Now process the remaining <td> tags
    Loop

End Sub
```